# Transforming a Date Column with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to transform a column in my data set that has number of days from the start date of a period into a date.

Here's an example of what I am trying to achieve in pandas:

[image]

```
#This doesn't not work 
sdate = datetime(2015, 10, 1)
ndf['Date'] = ndf['Date'].apply(lambda x: sdate + x)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to convert your `'Date'` column to `timedelta` and then add the `sdate` to it.

An Example of vectorized way of doing it -

```
sdate = datetime(2015, 10, 1)
ndf['Date'] = pd.to_timedelta(ndf['Date'],unit='d') + sdate
```

This would make the column to be of type `datetime` (not string).

---

Demo -

```
In [18]: from datetime import datetime

In [19]: sdate = datetime(2015, 10, 1)

In [20]: df
Out[20]:
   Date
0     1
1     1
2     3
3     5

In [21]: df['Date'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['Date'],unit='d') + sdate

In [22]: df
Out[22]:
        Date
0 2015-10-02
1 2015-10-02
2 2015-10-04
3 2015-10-06
```